# How to mention mentioned users in a message?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I've been trying to figure this out in a while but honestly i can't seem to wrap my head around it, I've figured out that u can add roles to users by doing a simple add_roles with message.mentions[0] but i can't seem to figure out how to mention a mentioned user in a message, Here is my current code Any help would be great!

```
    if message.content.lower().startswith('/slap'):
        mention = message.mentions[0]
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, mention + "got slapped by {0.author.mention}".format(message))
```

Comment: [`message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) is a list of `Member` objects.  `author` is also a member object, so you mention them in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.mentions` returns a list of discord.Member objects. You can ping those members by using `member.mention`

So to ping the person you'd need

```
member = message.mentions[0] # Probably in a try block
content = "{0.mention} ... {1.author.mention}".format(member, message)
await bot.send_message(..., content)
```

or to get a list of mentions, you can probably get away with

```
# After checking the length of the list (2 or more)
mentions = [m.mention for m in message.mentions]
mention_list = ", ".join(mentions[:-1]) + " and " + mentions[-1]
```